# Generating plots in a simple way

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

Yesterday I learnt how to make simpe plots using `tikzpicture` and I'm very satisfied of the result:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.6]
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=$\delta$,
        ylabel=$U_2$]
    \addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue] plot coordinates {
        (1,4)
        (4,2)
    };
    \addlegendentry{$\beta_2$}
    \addplot[smooth,color=red,mark=x]
        plot coordinates {
            (1,0)
            (4,9)
        };
    \addlegendentry{$\beta_1$}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

However now I have to make more complex plots (e.g. boxplot) and I cannot think of doing it manually. Up to now I have a Matlab script which reads a certain amount data and generates a figure. I exclude to save it as .png anymore because I want a vectorial image inside my document.
The better way I found is to use `matlab2tikz`. I tried it but it gives me errors. Because I cannot access newer versions of Matlab (which wouldn't resolve anything, I think, as the figure is generated without errors. The errors are when I compile LaTeX code.) and because I don't like to deal eternally with parser errors (I have few time so I cannot risk to loose too much time on this) I was looking for another way of doing it.

What do other people do when they want to add a vectorial plot from matlab/octave/gnuplot? Is `matlab2tiks` the gold standard or is there some other way?

(I know that I could compute my personal tikz boxplot from raw data with a not-too-complex script, and I like the idea, but I'm guessing if there is already something that does it)

Comment: What errors do you get when you compile the code from `matlab2tikz`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. They are 98. I'm trying to find a way of copying and pasting them from Kyle. I cite you a couple: "Missing \endcsname inserted };" here's another: "There is not line to end };" and so on.

Comment: The first one(s) could be the most important. Open the `.log` file and you'll find them.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. The first two errors are those I wrote. I put the log here: http://pastebin.com/wi4dkzYu and the .tex here: http://pastebin.com/Y1Kzq8Up and the tikz here: http://pastebin.com/Npig30W6 if you want take a look. Thank you!

Comment: You have an outdated TeX-distribution, with old versions of TikZ and `pgfplots`. On my system (a recently updated TeX Live 2013) your plot works fine. Install TeX Live 2013 from TUG.org (see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu) if you can.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you, I'll follow your advice. Then, returning to my question, I deduce that matlab2tikz is the best way of doing this, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boxplots are described in chapter 5.9.1 of the [PGFPLOTS manual.](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf)

Like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [
    ytick={1,2,3},
    yticklabels={Index 0, Index 1, Index 2},
    ]
    \addplot+[
    boxplot prepared={
      median=1,
      upper quartile=1.2,
      lower quartile=0.4,
      upper whisker=1.5,
      lower whisker=0.2
    },
    ] coordinates {};
    \addplot+[
    boxplot prepared={
      median=2,
      upper quartile=2.3,
      lower quartile=1.5,
      upper whisker=2.7,
      lower whisker=1
    },
    ] coordinates {};
    \addplot+[
    boxplot prepared={
      median=0.7,
      upper quartile=1.4,
      lower quartile=0.5,
      upper whisker=1.9,
      lower whisker=0.1
    },
    ] coordinates {};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: boxplot]

If you do want to use matlab. Try to save your image as a pdf or eps, since it is vector based, you won't loose quality.

Comment: I tried to "print file.pdf" from matlab and it actually looses quality. Moreover I'd prefer to have a tikz figure in order to customize it from tex editor. I didn't try .eps, maybe I'll try it later, thank you for the answer!

Comment: I would prefer the tikz option as well. But do note that the matlab print command has an option -r to set the resolution of the
graphic - try setting it to something like -r300  (it will be the dpi quality)